# Passar dados do Firebase Database por Intent e recuperar em outra activity

Tags: android, firebase, onclick, android-intent, firebase-database

Este é o trecho do código do meu Fragment no qual preciso passar um parametro (id do Firebase DB) por meio de uma Intent gerada pelo `Adapter.setOnClickListener`:

```
...
viewHolder.eventoCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String evento_id = evento.getId();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EventoActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("evento_id", evento_id);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Log.i(TAG_CLICK, "clicou no evento...");
                }
            });
...
```

E este é o código da activity que precisa recuperar a Id enviada para mostrar dados mais detalhados:

```
public class EventoActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_evento);

    setUpToolbar();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("evento_id")) {
        Evento e = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("evento_id");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(e.getNome());
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ImageView appBarImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.appBarImg);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(e.geturl_foto()).into(appBarImg);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            EventoFragment frag = new EventoFragment();
            frag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.EventoFragment, frag).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Tenho uma activity como esta:

[image]

ao selecionar o item preciso abrir algo como esta outra activity:

[image]

Este é o erro mostrado no meu logcat:

```
03-21 14:18:12.390 27190-27190/br.com.ministeriosonhodedeus.sonhodedeus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: br.com.ministeriosonhodedeus.sonhodedeus, PID: 27190
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.ministeriosonhodedeus.sonhodedeus/br.com.ministeriosonhodedeus.sonhodedeus.activity.EventoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String br.com.ministeriosonhodedeus.sonhodedeus.domain.Evento.getNome()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String br.com.ministeriosonhodedeus.sonhodedeus.domain.Evento.getNome()' on a null object reference
   at br.com.ministeriosonhodedeus.sonhodedeus.activity.EventoActivity.onCreate(EventoActivity.java:30)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o que está errado?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você está passando uma string id (`String evento_id = evento.getId();`) para a outra activity mas está usando-o como se fosse um objeto (`Evento e = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("evento_id");`), acredito que o erro está na lógica

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam tentei do seguinte jeito na activity que recebe os parametros e continuou com o mesmo erro
`String event_id = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("event_id");`

Comment: Sim porque mesmo que mude o tipo da variável para String você ainda está usando a varável `e` como um objeto (`e.getNome()`), você deve fazer uma nova busca no firebase para pegar o objeto a partir do id ou passar todo o objeto de uma activity para outra

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam como posso fazer para passar todo o objeto para a Intent?
Pois precisarei recuperar o objeto com seus respectivos atributos do BD na próxima activity.

Comment: Teria que ser algo assim?

`Evento e = new Evento("evento_id", evento.getId());
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), EventoActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("evento_id", e.getId());`

Answer (score 1):

Vou deixar um exemplo de como eviar um objeto de uma tela para outra basta implementar trocando os get set e classe.

Tela 1:

```
btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

            /* Instanciando objeto que será enviado para a Tela 2 */
            Usuario u = new Usuario();

            /* Recebendo os valores no objeto para enviar para
               a próxima tela através do método putExtra() */
            u.setLogin("usuario tal");
            u.setSenha("123");

            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tela2.class);

            //Passando os valores
            it.putExtra("usuario", u);

            startActivity(it);

            //Opcional: encerrar a activity
            //finish();
       }
 });
```

Tela 2:

```
//Recebendo os valores passados como String
Usuario u = (Usuario) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("usuario");
String login = u.getLogin();
String senha = u.getSenha();
```

Classe:

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
    //...
}
```

Fonte: [Github](https://github.com/thiago-cury/aulas-android/tree/master/ExIntentSegundaTelaEnviandoObjetoAPI19)